# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 328, 328, 3) vs (None, 1)) with autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build an autoencoder with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import sys
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPool1D, Reshape
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Activation, Add, Concatenate
from keras import regularizers
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, RMSprop, Adadelta
import keras.backend as K
from keras.objectives import mean_squared_error
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import np_utils

def create_block(input, chs): ## Convolution block of 2 layers
    x = input
    for i in range(2):
        x = Conv2D(chs, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return x
input_img = Input(shape=(328, 328, 3))

block1 = create_block(input_img, 32)
x = MaxPool2D(2)(block1)
block2 = create_block(x, 64)

#Middle
x = MaxPool2D(2)(block2)
middle = create_block(x, 128)

# Decoder
block3 = create_block(middle, 64)
up1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(block3)
block4 = create_block(up1, 32)
up2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(block4)

# output
x = Conv2D(3, 1)(up2)
output = Activation("sigmoid")(x)


autoencoder = Model(input_img, output)
autoencoder.compile(SGD(1e-3, 0.9), loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()
```

For my training data i use:

```
img_height = 328
img_width = 328

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

When I try to run it with autoencoder.fit(
train_ds,
validation_data=val_ds,
epochs=50
) I get the ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 328, 328, 3) vs (None, 1))

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an autoencoder, your target needs to be your input. The error you're trying to minimize is the reconstruction loss, so the output needs to be your original input. By default, Keras directory iterators will return the target (e.g., 0 and 1), not the input.

```
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    validation_split=0.2
)
```

Specify `class_mode='input'`. Note that I seem to have a different version, so I had to replace `image_size` by `target_size` to have it run for me.

```
train_ds = generator.flow_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  class_mode='input'
)
```

Here's a complete working example with generated data, which uses the autoencoder architecture you gave:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, UpSampling2D, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential

def create_block(input, chs):
    x = input
    for i in range(2):
        x = Conv2D(chs, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return x
input_img = Input(shape=(328, 328, 3))

block1 = create_block(input_img, 32)
x = MaxPool2D(2)(block1)
block2 = create_block(x, 64)

#Middle
x = MaxPool2D(2)(block2)
middle = create_block(x, 128)

# Decoder
block3 = create_block(middle, 64)
up1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(block3)
block4 = create_block(up1, 32)
up2 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(block4)

# output
x = Conv2D(3, 1)(up2)
output = Activation("sigmoid")(x)

X = np.random.rand(8, 328, 328, 3).astype(np.float32)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, output)
autoencoder.compile('adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()

generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

train_ds = generator.flow(
  x=X,
  y=X
)

history = autoencoder.fit(train_ds)
```

```
Train for 1 steps
1/1 [==============================] - 9s 9s/step - loss: 0.8827
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. Since I am very new to Keras I would like to know if it is normal to work with these data generators? Because in all the examples with mnist, cifar10 etc. the use normal numpy arrays.

Comment: These generators have the advantage of not loading the entire dataset in memory, as opposed to toy datasets (e.g., MNIST, CIFAR-10). If you're dealing with images in a folder, definitely use directory iterators for efficiency. Tutorials use the MNIST/CIFAR-10 for reproducibility – you can just copy and paste the code and it runs. EDIT: in my example it would change nothing at all since the array was already in memory, but you get the point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment regarding my answer! I confused autoencoder with encoder-decoder networks, as the usage of both terms is often mistaken by people. I now understand both,thanks for that! Thanks again for pointing that out, I will delete my answer as it does not match to the question.

Comment: Not a problem!!